# How to know the remaining space in pdf in iText pdf

Tags: java, itext

I want to know that how many spaces are left after adding contents in pdf page. Is there any way so that I can track that some space is there so that I can accommodate 3 to 4 lines in one page or else I can create a new document page to put the contents.

I want to do in the following manner -

```
if( getRemainingSpace() < pageSize)
//Create new page
else
put contents in the same page
```

Answer (score 5):

*As you use the [itext](/questions/tagged/itext) tag (not [itext7](/questions/tagged/itext7)), I assume you are using iText 5.5.x.*

The `PdfWriter` class provides a method which returns the current vertical position:

```
/**
 * Use this method to get the current vertical page position.
 * @param ensureNewLine Tells whether a new line shall be enforced. This may cause side effects
 *   for elements that do not terminate the lines they've started because those lines will get
 *   terminated.
 * @return The current vertical page position.
 */
public float getVerticalPosition(final boolean ensureNewLine)
```

Thus, to retrieve the vertical extent of the remaining main content space on the current page, you merely have to retrieve this vertical position value and subtract the y position of the bottom page margin (which you can retrieve using the `Document` method `bottom()`).

The value you get is in default user space units (which in turn defaults to 1/72 inch).

The number of *lines* fitting into this space obviously depend on the fonts and other parameters (font size, leading, ...) you want to use on those lines.

Comment: how do I achieve the same in `itext7`? what is the equivalent method to find the current vertical position?

Comment: @Vikas Please make that a question in its own right. Be aware, though, that iText 7 has a much more dynamic rendering model, there is not necessarily a global current position but probably only numerous current positions of multiple more local rendering contexts.

Comment: How do I achieve it in a velocity template using html cde?

Comment: That's an entirely different question. Thus, please post it as a question in its own right.